# How to insert date in mysql from three drop down list into one cell as a single value using jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp, date

i want to select value from three dropdown option select and insert in one field/cell in mysql database

```
            <select name="month">
 <option value="01">January</option>
 <option value="02">February</option>
 <option value="03">March</option>
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="year">
 <option value="1980">1980</option>
 <option value="1981">1981</option>
 <option value="1982">1982</option>
 <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

and this is my dateFormat.jsp page but when i hit submit it shows null value....plzz help
yes i tried this code:

```
<% try { 
        String year=request.getParameter("Year");  
        String month=request.getParameter("Month");  
        String day=request.getParameter("Day");  
        String myDate=request.getParameter("Year").trim()+"-"+request.getParameter("Month").trim()+"-"+request.getParameter("Day").trim();
        java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(0000-00-00);  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raqib007","root","sesame");  
        Statement st=con.createStatement();  
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("update pictures date=? where id='1'");  
        ps.setDate(1,date.valueOf(myDate));  
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();  
        if(i==1)  
                   {  
            out.println("Date success");  
                   }  
    }  
    catch(Exception e)  
                   {  
        out.println(" "+e.getMessage());  
                   }
%>
```

Comment: well first you need to pad your days value with `0`'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, pad the values of the day value with 0 to get values such as: `01, 02, 03, etc.`

Then use this variable:

```
String myDate = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
```

And insert it as a string into your database:

```
ps.setDate(1,myDate);
```

**Note:** I am not a JSP programmer, so I am sort of guessing from what I know about other languages about this last line. But the point is do not type or convert the `string myDate` to

`date date.myDate ...` before sending it to the database, send the string instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store the date to your database , first of all you need to create a column(dob) and datatype can be date. after you create that column make sure that your date format in which you want to tore is mentioned. the column you have jut created stores date in Y-m-d format.
first of all  grab your date(y-m-d) with post in a single string variable and mention the format . let it be $dob.
 if you want to create a column(dob) in existing db

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN dob date 
$dob=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'].'-'.$_POST['year']));
```

now insert $dob into your database from php script.
 may be it will help you

Comment: I don't think the OP is using PHP

Comment: his query about inserting date as a whole single string in db is wht i  think he is really looking for.

Comment: what are you actually looking for.. is it inserting your date in your db or somethingwent wrong in your code?

Comment: you will get null value if you change the format of date storing into database. i mean if you have a datatype of date in you db column and you are trying to get the format as d-m-y or m-d-y . you will get null value. try using the format given above as Y-m-d and leme know.